# How can I restore a new version of database on the old version with keeping old data?

Tags: sql-server-2008, database-restore

I want to restore a new version of database with new stored procedure on the old version, How can I do it with keeping old data of tables on old version of my database?

THANX

Answer (score 0):

Simple: **you CANNOT**.

SQL Server is **NOT** backwards compatible - you **CANNOT** with any method, trick, hack, workaround get a newer database (as `.mdf/.ldf` to attach or a a `.bak` to restore) onto an older version of SQL Server.

It just cannot be done - period.

You will need to script out your database changes to `.sql` files to update the structure on your old server, and you'll need to use SQL or a third-party tool (like [Red-Gate SQL Data Compare](https://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-data-compare/)) to copy over the data, too.

Re-reading your question, I'm not quite sure whether you're talking about "going back" in terms of SQL Server versions (not quite clear, really) - if you just need to bring the changes from a newer database to an older version of the database on the same version of SQL Server - then I'd highly recommend tools like [Red-Gate SQL Compare](https://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-compare/) (and the above mentioned Data Compare) for the job.

Those allow you to find structural and data difference between two databases and create update scripts that you can run on the "old" database to bring it up to the same structure as the "new" database.